# AWK merging of two files intercrossing lines

Tags: awk, playlist, gawk

and thank you for taking a moment for reading this, at this point i am trying to finish and polish a little radio station using icecast, everything actually is already working.

however there is this program called ezstream, what it does is just stream music into icecast when nobody is live, its the most common autodj, wich uses playlists.

said playlist can play once and the program closes, and thats exactly what i want to exploit here, i managed to automatically create two different playlists, one with all the music, and the other one with commercials, jingles and soundbytes, and basically they are just a list of files stored on the computer. like the following, obviously they have names and stuff.

this would be the playlist1

```
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album2/title2.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album2/title3.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album2/title4.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album2/title5.mp3
```

the playlist2 is very similar but it contains only commercials so it looks like this

```
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial3.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial4.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial5.mp3
```

the part where im critically stuck is in mergin those one in a 2:1 or 3:1 ratio (if you could give me a hand with both codes it would be awesome too.

the final output is supposed to look something like this

```
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3

/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3

/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3
```

and so on until both the files are merged completely, so far i've only managed to find this code, but for some reason its not working, it gives errors related to syntax and missing a < symbol.

AWK code:

```
awk ‘FNR==NR{

song[FNR]=$0; 
next 
}

{

print song[FNR+line];line++;

print song[FNR+line]

print $0

}’ playlist1.m3u playlist2.m3u
```

all this should be outputed to a third file say `mergedplaylists.m3u`

i didnt created that code, altho i've tried fiddling with it for a while, one thing that is not very clear to me is why does it say "song" in there, can it be changed for something else? say "album" ?

the code does not work at all, neither writes something at the output file (nor i know if its correct).

i hope some1 can give me a hand with the particular case, AWK seems to be helpful but its very cryptic and im finding a lot of problems to understand it...

thank you again

Comment: The syntax problem with that code is the use of forward-tick (`\``) instead of back-tick (`'`) as the first character of the awk script. The word "song" is just a variable name used to name an array - you can use any word you like for a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put 2 songs before each commercial:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{ song[++numSongs]=$0; next }
{
   for (i=1;i<=2;i++)
      print song[++songNr]
   print
}
songNr == numSongs { exit }
' playlist1.m3u playlist2.m3u
```

Change the "2" to "3" or whatever as you see fit.

Alternative implementation based on comments below:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ interval = (interval ? interval : 3) }

NR==FNR { songs[++numSongs] = $0; next }

{ commercials[++numCommercials] = $0 }

END {
    for (songNr=1; songNr<=numSongs; songNr++) {

        print songs[songNr]

        if ( !( songNr % interval) && (++commercialNr in commercials) )
            print commercials[commercialNr]

    }

}
$
$ cat songs.txt
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title5.mp3
$
$ cat commercials.txt
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial3.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial4.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial5.mp3
$
$ awk -f tst.awk songs.txt commercials.txt
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title5.mp3
$
$ awk -v interval=1 -f tst.awk songs.txt commercials.txt
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial5.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title5.mp3
$
$ awk -v interval=2 -f tst.awk songs.txt commercials.txt
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title5.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial5.mp3
$
$ awk -v interval=4 -f tst.awk songs.txt commercials.txt
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album1/title5.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title1.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title3.mp3
/home/mp3/commercials/commercial2.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title4.mp3
/home/mp3/albums/album2/title5.mp3
```

Here's awk:

```
BEGIN{ interval = (interval ? interval : 3) }

NR==FNR { songs[++numSongs] = $0; next }

{ commercials[++numCommercials] = $0 }

END {
    for (songNr=1; songNr<=numSongs; songNr++) {

        print songs[songNr]

        if ( !(songNr % interval) && (++commercialNr <= numCommercials) )
            print commercials[commercialNr]

    }

}
```

Here's C-like pseudo-code:

```
void main() {

    FILE *filep;
    char *line;

    char *songs[1000];
    char *commercials[1000];

    int FNR = 0;
    int NR = 0;
    int interval = 0;
    int numSongs = 0;
    int numCommercials = 0;
    int songNr = 0;
    int commercialNr = 0;
    int argNr = 0;

    /* BEGIN */
    if (ARGV[++argNr] == "interval") {
         interval = ARGV[++argNr];
    }
    interval = (interval ? interval : 3);

    for (++argNr;argNr<=ARGC;argNr++) {
       filep = ARGV[argNr];
       FNR = 0;
       while ( fgets(line,filep) > 0 ) {
          NR++;
          FNR++;

          if (NR == FNR) { songs[++numSongs] = line; continue; }

          commercials[++numCommercials] = line;

       }
    }

    /* END */
    for (songNr=1; songNr<=numSongs; songNr++) {

        printf("%s\n",songs[songNr]);

        if ( !(songNr % interval) && (++commercialNr <= numCommercials) )
                printf("%s\n",commercials[commercialNr]);
        }

    }

    return;
}
```

The only change I made to the awk script for ease of comparison was to remove the "in" operator for which there's no clear C equivalent.

Hope that helps clarify what the awk script is doing.

Comment: i got a syntax error on the last print, does it matter if the script contains the word "Song" altho there aint files called that way? (except for one actual, /home/mp3/albums/The Best of/02 Song 2.mp3 (by Blur ehehehe)

Comment: It's not the "print". I copy/pasted your example and tweaked that to create the script I posted but it turns out the final quote character in your question wasn't a normal quote, hence the syntax error. I fixed my answer. The variable name used in the script has absolutely nothing to do with any filed names that exist outside of the script. The only 2 file names mentioned above are playlist1.m3u and playlist2.m3u

Comment: im sorry, i just cant make it work, i tried typing it on command line, no luck, also cutted and pasted in the .sh script (the one that currently creates the first playlists and it gives me an error, also tried in a shell script by itself to see it working alone, got interpreter error, so i changed it to #!usr/bin/awk and ran it, i got undeterminated regexp error, i dont consider myself such a noob, but this awk thingie is really making itself harder and harder to me

Comment: You are almost certainly doing just 1 fundamental thing wrong. We just need to figure out what that is. To get started: Copy/paste my script above into your window and hit return.  Now copy/paste what you did and the output you got into your original question above so we can see the error message. In case you are on Solaris do NOT use /usr/bin/awk or /bin/awk as those are both old, broken awk - use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead.

Comment: i just redid all the copy pasting process and it works, i had to twist a little at the end, mainly for the filenames and by the time it finishes i just added a > playlist-final.m3u and the command to execute the ezstream, it works, however i noticed something as there are less commercials than songs the playlist will only be as long as commercials are shown, meaning 3 commercials will pop only 6 songs, it doesnt really really matter tho, as the list will continuously refresh itself once the ezstream is done playing the current one and will randomly select songs again

Comment: If you can describe the algorithm you want wrt number of songs and number of commercials, I can show you how to write it in awk.

Comment: as the number of songs will constantly vary, as they will be added overtime, same as commercials, i suppose it would be rather pointless, there is a good thing i noticed however, all commercials will be played each time the playlist is renewed, and the songs will always be different, because the original playlist1 and playlist2 are passed through a sort -R playlist1.m3u > random-playlist1.m3u so they get randomized, and playlist1 is actually constructed from a series of individual playlist that are manually created when the album is uploaded using cat *.m3u|grep -v commercials > playlist1.m3u

Comment: OK, I added an alternative way this could be implemented that might be easier for you to work with and modify if necessary. With this approach you could dynamically figure out the "interval" value based on numSongs and numCommercials when you enter the END section so you automatically always use all of your songs plus all of your commercials if that's desirable. Enjoy!

Comment: thats crazy, thank you very much, i honestly cant get myself to understand awk, its too cryptic, but hey you got it nailed, again thank you and have a pleasant day :D

Comment: Huh, I can't imagine what's cryptic about that script. I'll add a C-like pseudo-code translation to see if that helps.